# Automated + scheduled fetching from CDC tables

Tags: sql-server

I am a Java developer and I understand a little of SQL Server DB admin. :)

**Objective :**

Write a Java program that, **as scheduled**, can fetch the data from **ALL** the SQL Server Change Tables(CT) as per the [Changed Data Capture (CDC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx).

I created a TEST schema with some tables and enabled CDC on a couple of them

[image]

Now, I can query the individual CT tables and get the data :

[image]

The challenge begins when I want to schedule these queries via a Java program. As shown in the queries, I am using a timestamp against the column tran_begin_time to get the relevant start_lsn, there are some challenges :

1. The DB server and the machine hosting the Java program can have different clock timings, hence, I need to store the tran_begin_time or something to ensure that no data is missed/imported duplicate
2. There can be multiple LSNs for EACH table over period of time. Even if I manage to store all of them, per table(this itself is cumbersome), I dunno how to use them in the next execution
3. I was wondering that I should only store the tran_begin_time and tran_end_time from the cdc.lsn_time_mapping table but then I get only the start_lsn which, somehow, I need to backtrack to each CT(Change Table) to get the data(I am really apprehensive about this approach)
   [image]
4. I am still talking about ONE container DB(here, TEST), there will several like this

How shall I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

As you've probably already surmised, using times will lead to subtle bugs at some point. I'd suggest trafficking in LSNs directly. An LSN (short for Log Sequence Number) is a way that the database tracks and orders changes to the data. LSNs are monotone increasing. Here's what I propose:

1. Create a table to store your LSN values and whether processing has completed for that interval. Something like `create table LSNBoundaries (LSN binary(10) not null, IsProcessingComplete bit not null);`
2. Call `sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()` to get the latest LSN in the database. Store it in the table with a value for the bit column as 0 (i.e. not complete)
3. For each table that you want to process, select from the _CT table where [__$start_lsn] <= (the value from above)
4. Once you've processed all of the tables, mark the row as complete

Now your initial setup is complete. For your ongoing processing, you'll do something like the following:

1. Insert a new row into the table with values `(sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 0)`. This will be the upper boundary for your query.
2. Find the value in the table with the highest LSN value that has been successfully processed. That will represent the lower boundary.
3. For each _CT table, select from it `where [__$start_lsn] > @lower_lsn and [__$start_lsn] <= @upper_lsn`
4. Once all tables are complete, mark that boundary as complete.

If you do this right, you won't miss any data.

Comment: I proceeded with this approach but as I had mentioned in my original question, the things get tricky when several 'SELECT * FROM *_CT*  queries execute in a loop AND at regular intervals. In the above approach, I store just ONE lsn and reuse it to decide the bounds, during next execution, thus, NO per-table lsn is stored. Now, there's an issue if in the loop, the select fails for, say 2 tables, and succeeds for the rest 3. On the next execution, how would I proceed with a single LSN ?